# Is it okay to have COLLSCAN for a collection with only few documents?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection which has just two documents in it, both are used to keep track of a certain count.
I know this will never have more than 2 documents, but when the counter value is increased, it uses findAndModify and shows COLLSCAN.
I believe it is okay to have COLLSCAN here as having an index over they search key wont give any performance benefits, any thoughts?

Comment: You wont need an index for querying a collection with couple of documents (or even with few thousands of documents). Sometimes, a plan with COLLSCAN can perform better than one with IXSCAN (even with lot more than few documents). An index on a collection with a few documents is just an overhead, in terms of storage, memory and performance (during insert and update operations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes are not always good. The main things to understand how they work are:

1. Index use memory in exchange for better performance. Every time you want to use an index, you need to load it to MongoDB RAM (if its not there yet).
2. When the Mongo engine gets a query it needs to check which index to use (if there are some) and for each index check if it can use it (contains the relevant query parameters which are union of find, projection and sort). If not Mongo decide whether to use it (best found index) or doing a collection scan (or both).
3. Index requires handling - every insert/update/delete operation requires updating the index.

There is a lot of overhead to use an index so the benefit should be several times greater than a simple collection scan. You can continue reading [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/).